# Can i access iCloud storage from different BundleID?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, icloud, bundle-identifier

I have built an iOS application using the following bundleID com.XXX1234.a client using Enterprise Apple Account for internal distribution. The apps have the features of backup the application data to iCLOUD.

Now I have to move the application to Apple Store, so I have to build compile the same application using Company Apple Account with a different bundleID com.xxx.client.

My problem now is that the data backup from the old application (com.XXX1234.client) cannot be restored to the new application (com.xxx.client), is this because the new application cannot access to the CLOUD for the old bundleID?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to access data with a new app that you have created under a different developer account?  If so, that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes, the old app is build using Enterprise developer account, now the customer wants to distribution the app in Apple Store, and i no longer can use the Enterprise developer account.

Comment: You cannot access data for an app that has been developed under a different developer account.  Or would you be willing to let anyone access your app's data by just using its bundle ID?  That simply does not make sense.

Comment: I got what you meant. The issue I'm facing here is both app is created by me and I'm changing the distribution channel. 

All the old app users will loss all their data when they switch to the new app downloaded from Apple Store.

Comment: It does not matter who's created what.  The only approach you could take is to sell the old app to yourself under a new developer account.

Comment: How do you sell the old app to a new developer account?

Comment: Why are you asking me?  Ask Apple or go to their developer forums.

Comment: That approach isn't open to you since the current distribution is via the enterprise program.  You can only transfer apps between App Store accounts.  There is no way that the new app can access the old data in place.   You could update the enterprise app to add a functionality to *export data* that can then be *imported* into the App Store version.

Comment: I already have this features to backup to iCLOUD. But the new app cannot locate the backup. That is my initial question of can the old app and new app access the same iCLOUD storage login with the same AppleID?

Comment: As I said, you need to provide the ability to export the data to a file that the user can store on iCloud Drive or any other provider that is available in the files app. This would require an update to your enterprise version. Your problem isn't the Apple ID it is the sandbox; your two apps are prevented from reading each other's data in iCloud